# Why does my javascript slideshow not work and result in a "Cannot set properties of undefined(setting 'className')?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a slideshow in javascript, where pressing the 'next' and 'previous' buttons should take you to the next and previous slides.

When I run the code, the slideshow doesn't work, instead, the new "slides" end up coming below the existing slide. Apart from this, there is an error, "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'className')".

Here is my html:

```
<div id="slideshow_container">
<!-- This is the start of the slideshow--> 
<div id="bg" class="slide_active">  <!-- First slideshow element -->
  <div id="info">
    <br><br>
    <section class="who"> 
      <h2>
        Who are we?
      </h2> <br>
      <p>
        We are the organisation responsible for bringing together the Bangladeshi community in Oman. By hosting a wide range of events and gatherings, we ensure that everyone from Bangladesh is kept engaged here!
      </p>
    </section>
    <br><br>
    <section class="who">
      <h2>
        Our Story
      </h2>
    </section>
     <br><br> 
    <section class="who">
      <h2>
        Our Misssion
      </h2>
      <br>
      <p>
        To unite the Bangladeshi community in Oman
      </p>
    </section>
    <br><br>
    <section class="who">
      <h2>
        Our Vision
      </h2>
      <br>
      <p>
        To reach out to all Bengali people living in Oman.
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <a id="prev" onclick="Prev_Slide(1)">Previous</a>
  <a id="next" onclick="Next_Slide(1)">Next</a>
</div> 
<div id="message_div" class="slide"><!-- Second slideshow element -->
  <br><br>
  <h2 id="message">
    Message from our CEO
  </h2>
  <p id="belief">
    Our CEO believes....
  </p>
</div>
<div id="members" class="slide">
  <h2 id="member_head">
    Our members...
  </h2>
  
    
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
#img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: fill;
}


#info{
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.who{ 
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}

h2{
    font-weight: bold;
}

#bg{
  background-color: green;
  width:1600px;
  height: 619px;
}

#prev{
  position:relative;
  top:575px;
  left:10px;
  font-family: Segoe Print;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;

}

#next{
  position:relative;
  top:575px;
  left:1400px;
  font-family: Segoe Print;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

#slideshow_container{
  width: 1600px;
  height: 619px;
  position:relative;
}

.slide{
  display:none;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.slide_active{
  display:block;
}

#message_div{
  text-align: center;
}

#belief{
  text-align: center;
}
```

And finally, here is my javascript:

```
let Slide_number = 1;
show_slides(Slide_number);

function Next_Slide(n){
  show_slides(Slide_number += n);
}

function Prev_Slide(n){
  show_slides(Slide_number -= n);
}

/* Literally the slide number(not indexed) */

function show_slides(n){
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  if (n>slides.length){
    Slide_number = 1;
  }
  if (n<1){
    Slide_number = slides.length
  }
  for(i=0; i<slides.length; i++){
    slides[i].className = "slide";
  }
  slides[Slide_number-1].className = "slide_active";  
}
```

Can someone please help me out with exactly what is wrong with my approach? I do not understand the issue. I am using bootstrap, but I don't think that would interfere with my code much.

Comment: When you make a slide active, you remove the `slide` class, so it will not be found the next time you call `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-I - it opens the debugger. Give it a go, in no-time at all you'll be wondering how you ever wrote web-apps without using it. Since, it will tell you where the errors are and how your code is actually running. Rather useful to me when my imagined course of action is not mirrored by what the code actually does.

Comment: Investigate classList.add and classList.remove to make sure your slides always keep the slide class. Also ensure that your tests on the slide index number are correct. Remember that arrays start their index at 0 so your test n>slides.length should probably be n>=slides.length

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the *classnames* of the sildes every time you click on *anchor tag*. You need addition assignment operator `+=` and a **space** for
it. So you can add class to that element.

---

You can also use `classList.add()` method.

```
slides[Slide_number - 1].classList.add("slide_active");
```

---

```js
let Slide_number = 1;
show_slides(Slide_number);

function Next_Slide(n) {
  show_slides(Slide_number += n);
}

function Prev_Slide(n) {
  show_slides(Slide_number -= n);
}


function show_slides(n) {
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");

  if (n > slides.length) Slide_number = 1;
  if (n < 1) Slide_number = slides.length;

  console.log(Slide_number);

  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].className = "slide";
  }
   slides[Slide_number - 1].className += " slide_active";
}
```

```css
#img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: fill;
}

#info {
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.who {
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#bg {
  background-color: green;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 619px;
}

#prev {
  position: relative;
  top: 575px;
  left: 10px;
  font-family: Segoe Print;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

#next {
  position: relative;
  top: 575px;
  left: 1400px;
  font-family: Segoe Print;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

#slideshow_container {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 619px;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.slide_active {
  display: block;
}

#message_div {
  text-align: center;
}

#belief {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow_container">
  <!-- This is the start of the slideshow-->
  <div id="bg" class="slide_active">
    <!-- First slideshow element -->
    <div id="info">
      <br><br>
      <section class="who">
        <h2>
          Who are we?
        </h2> <br>
        <p>
          We are the organisation responsible for bringing together the Bangladeshi community in Oman. By hosting a wide range of events and gatherings, we ensure that everyone from Bangladesh is kept engaged here!
        </p>
      </section>
      <br><br>
      <section class="who">
        <h2>
          Our Story
        </h2>
      </section>
      <br><br>
      <section class="who">
        <h2>
          Our Misssion
        </h2>
        <br>
        <p>
          To unite the Bangladeshi community in Oman
        </p>
      </section>
      <br><br>
      <section class="who">
        <h2>
          Our Vision
        </h2>
        <br>
        <p>
          To reach out to all Bengali people living in Oman.
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
    <a id="prev" onclick="Prev_Slide(1)">Previous</a>
    <a id="next" onclick="Next_Slide(1)">Next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="message_div" class="slide">
    <!-- Second slideshow element -->
    <br><br>
    <h2 id="message">
      Message from our CEO
    </h2>
    <p id="belief">
      Our CEO believes....
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="members" class="slide">
    <h2 id="member_head">
      Our members...
    </h2>


  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

**Put your script just before the end of your body tag. If not you will get the undefined message.** Why? Because your by that time DOM is already loaded and ready for manipulation so you will have access to any element you wish to manipulate.

As for your slide showing under other, here is the working solution. When you add a classname with JS, if you want to replace an existing classname you can use `=` but if you want to add to an existing class, you need to keep a space before it
and use `+=` so that you don't overwrite the already existing class and you will have `class="existingclass addedclass"`. Also modified css, you can read the comment at the top. Also I have taken out **next** and **previous** button out of `#bg` div and placed it inside container directly, since it is a slide itself, your next slide won't be able to see those buttons. That's all. You can run the code directly to see it for yourself.

```js
let Slide_number = 1;
show_slides(Slide_number);

function Next_Slide(n){
  show_slides(Slide_number += n);
}

function Prev_Slide(n){
  show_slides(Slide_number -= n);
}

/* Literally the slide number(not indexed) */

function show_slides(n){

  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  if (n>slides.length){
    Slide_number = 1;
  }
  if (n<1){
    Slide_number = slides.length
  }
  for(i=0; i<slides.length; i++){
    slides[i].className = "slide";
  }
  // keep space before slide_active and use += instead
  slides[Slide_number-1].className += " slide_active";  
}
```

```css
/* gave slide container a green background so that you will be able to see white next and prev text, also removed style for #bg since it is a slide itself */
#img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: fill;
  }
  
  
  #info{
    width: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  
  .who{ 
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  }
  
  h2{
      font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  #prev{
    position:relative;
    top:575px;
    left:10px;
    font-family: Segoe Print;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
  
  }
  
  #next{
    position:relative;
    top:575px;
    left:1400px;
    font-family: Segoe Print;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
  }
  
  #slideshow_container{
    width: 1600px;
    height: 619px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: green;
  }
  
  .slide {
    display:none;
    object-fit: fill;
  }
  
  .slide_active{
    display:block;
  }
  
  #message_div{
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #belief{
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="slideshow_container">
        <a id="prev" onclick="Prev_Slide(1)">Previous</a>
        <a id="next" onclick="Next_Slide(1)">Next</a>
        <!-- This is the start of the slideshow--> 
        <div id="bg" class="slide">  <!-- First slideshow element -->
          <div id="info">
            <br><br>
            <section class="who"> 
              <h2>
                Who are we?
              </h2> <br>
              <p>
                We are the organisation responsible for bringing together the Bangladeshi community in Oman. By hosting a wide range of events and gatherings, we ensure that everyone from Bangladesh is kept engaged here!
              </p>
            </section>
            <br><br>
            <section class="who">
              <h2>
                Our Story
              </h2>
            </section>
             <br><br> 
            <section class="who">
              <h2>
                Our Misssion
              </h2>
              <br>
              <p>
                To unite the Bangladeshi community in Oman
              </p>
            </section>
            <br><br>
            <section class="who">
              <h2>
                Our Vision
              </h2>
              <br>
              <p>
                To reach out to all Bengali people living in Oman.
              </p>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div id="message_div" class="slide"><!-- Second slideshow element -->
          <br><br>
          <h2 id="message">
            Message from our CEO
          </h2>
          <p id="belief">
            Our CEO believes....
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="members" class="slide">
          <h2 id="member_head">
            Our members...
          </h2>
          
            
        </div>
```